# Gmail is not receiving emails from SendGrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have a Django app set up to send emails from my contact form via **SendGrid**.

The contact form should send emails to *contact@clientdomain.com*, which is an account using G Suite, so the client opens the email on Gmail.

However, the emails from the contact form are getting stuck on SendGrid with status *deferred* or *block*.

I tried changing the destination email from *contact@clientdomain.com* to *personal_email@gmail.com* and it worked just fine.

I don't know what else to do.

Here is my Activity Feed from SendGrid dashboard:

[image]

I read when the status is deferred, SendGrid keep trying to send the email again for the next 72h, but I have emails sent 3 days ago that never arrived on the inbox.

Anyone knows what could I do to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure they are using GSuite? I would double check their MX records to see if they are actually using GSuite directly and not through a third party firewall/spam filter setup.

Comment: @Selcuk now you made me think. Before, it was all set up on a server with cPanel, but now I'm using the PointDNS add-on to point the domain to Heroku and I think the MX records are not set up. I'll check it.

Comment: @Selcuk that is it! I just needed to add the MX records and everything started to work again, nice and shine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! Thanks to @Selcuk comment.

I had my domain pointing to a server with cPanel all set up.

Then I developed a new app, deployed it on Heroku and installed the PointDNS to get my domain poiting to the Heroku app.

When I did this, **I lost my MX records set up on my server with cPanel**.

All I had to do was to add the MX records for G Suite on PointDNS:

[image]

Comment: I also think it is very important to note that SendGrid allows domain verification, which allows the resulting email to be sent by SendGrid from your actual domain instead of the dedicated SendGrid domain. Simply matching MX records isn't always enough because the email can still appear spoofed to email providers, along with Gmail which I noticed in one of my implementations earlier today. https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/